# Traverse to get to innerHTML

Tags: selenium-ide

Using Selenium IDE, I need to verify the text "Schedule Entry Worksheet for ZBW - Boston Center" is present. I'd like to use AssertTextPresent to do this. I'm using Firebug to identify the path to the element.

Here's what I've done so far in IDE:
Command: assertTextPresent
Target: xpath=//html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/span
Value: Schedule Entry Worksheet for ZBW - Boston Center

However, I'm getting "[error] false" in the log section. Does anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly?

Below is a snippet HTML for the page:

```
<div id="worksheet_div" style="display: inline;">
    <div class="fg1" style="width: 2010px;">
        <div class="fgt">
            <span style="padding-right: 10px; background-color: #E3EFFF;">Schedule    Entry Worksheet for ZBW - Boston Center</span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

does it matter where the text is or just that it is somewhere? if it is the latter you could do something as simple as

```
css=span
```

if position on the page matter then need to add more structure to it

```
css=.fgt span
```

or similar.

it is also useful to use the firefinder plugin for firefox to debug xpath and css